# Nested routes with Subdomain-fu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, subdomain, nested-resources

I have some standard nested routes in my app, and I want to implement subdomains using the subdomain-fu gem.  So I'm currently doing this:

```
example.com/stores/name_of_store/products/name_of_product
```

and I want to do this:

```
name_of_store.example.com/products/name_of_product
```

There seems to have been some discussion about the failings of subdomain-fu with regard to nested routes in the subdomain-fu lighthouse tickets, but that lighthouse project is no longer public, so I can't review whatever conclusions they reached.

It would be great to hear from people regarding how you've implemented nested routes with subdomain-fu.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need nested routes at all to accomplish that.  You can just use subdomain_fu (or manually) to find the `current_store`, then a basic `ProductsController` that scopes its finds to products within a store:

```
# ApplicationController
def current_store
  @current_store ||= Store.find_by_subdomain(request.host)
end
helper_method :current_store

# ProductsController
def index
  @products = current_store.products.all
end
```

Comment: Wow. I've been looking for a way to clean-up my white-labelled domains for ages. At first I read your answer and thought "wait, what does that have to do with anything" but I stared at it for 5 minutes and all of a sudden it made sense! There is no need to interpret the parent resource instance in routing time. It can be interpreted programmatically! Thank you!!